# Black and white CSS background on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS sprite like:

HTML

```
<a id="estates" href="http://www.domain.com/estate"></a>
```

CSS

```
#estates {background-position: -200px 0px;width: 96px;height: 90px;}

#estates {background: url("http://www.domain.com/images/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;float: left;margin: 22px -2px 30px 33px;}
```

I would like when the user hovers over the link to change the image color to black and white or perhaps overlay a transparent png if that cannot happen?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can look into the CSS grayscale filter. It's along the lines of:

```
#estates:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */;
}
```

<del>Just don't forget to add the other hundred things you need for cross browser support</del>

I found the other hundred things and added them.

Comment: You need the grayscale.svg file for firefox right? Besides downloading it and placing it in the same folder, you can also use this: filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */

Comment: [This article](http://demosthenes.info/blog/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS) gives some background info.