# CSS filter not applying to background image

Tags: html, css

I am encountering a problem and trying to solve it but cant figure it out.

I am trying to apply a filter for a certain color on a div that has a background image, when hovering over another div. Yet it doesnt get applied, nor it applies when I try to do it on the item itself without hover state. I may have missed something but I am not entirely sure what. Its the first time i work with filters in CSS, so it comes a bit new to me.

```
<div class="background-1">
    <div class="container background-3 container-fix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="arts_btn" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center border-bottom border-bottom-hover-arts">
                 <a href="#" id="arts_logo">
                      Youtopia Arts
                 </a>
            </div>
            <div id="services_btn" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center border-bottom border-bottom-hover-service">
                 <a href="#" id="service_logo">
                      Yourtopia Services
                 </a>
            </div>
            <div id="fair_btn"class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center border-bottom border-bottom-hover-fair">
                 <a href="#" id="fair_logo">
                      Youtopian Fair
                 </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
    .background-1 {
background-color:#fff;
}

.background-2 {
background-color:#f7f8fa;
}

.background-3 {
background-color:#111;
}

#arts_logo {
background-image:url(http://placehold.it/90x90);
background-position:50% 50%;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
height: 100px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

#service_logo {
background-image:url(http://placehold.it/90x90);
background-position:50% 50%;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
height: 100px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

#fair_logo {
background-image:url(http://placehold.it/90x90);
background-position:50% 50%;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
height: 100px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

.border-bottom-hover-arts:hover {
border-bottom: 15px solid;
border-bottom-color: #6f2c31;
}

.border-bottom-hover-service:hover {
border-bottom: 15px solid;
border-bottom-color: #43396d;
}

.border-bottom-hover-fair:hover {
border-bottom: 15px solid;
border-bottom-color: #26645f;
}
.border-bottom{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    padding: 0px;
      border-bottom: 15px solid;
      border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.container-fix{
  padding: 0px;
}

.border-bottom-hover-arts:hover + #arts_logo{
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: saturate(41);
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
  -moz-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
  -o-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
}

.border-bottom-hover-fair:hover + #fair_logo{
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: saturate(41);
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
  -moz-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
  -o-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
}

.border-bottom-hover-fair:hover + #fair_logo{
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: saturate(41);
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
  -moz-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
  -o-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
}
```

(sorry for the weird indentation on the css part, but wordpress has a funny way with css files and throwing in extra lines)

I hope you guys can spot my problem, cause I missed it. I have added a link to a codepen as well.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwoWyP

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply CSS filters to background images...only actual HTML elements. If you're trying to affect the bg images and not the content another solution is required.

However, on the assumption you **are** trying to affect the **whole** element your selector is wrong.

```
.border-bottom-hover-arts:hover + #arts_logo{
    filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
    filter: saturate(41);
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
  -moz-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
  -o-filter: hue-rotate(356deg) saturate(41);
}
```

This assumed that `#arts_logo` is a sibling of `.border-bottom-hover-arts` when, in fact, it's a **child**

Your selector should thus be

```
 .border-bottom-hover-arts:hover #arts_logo
```

or

```
 .border-bottom-hover-arts:hover > #arts_logo
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/raRNwL)

[**Useful Article on Selectors**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: Thanks for that pointer on the child and sibling, in my haste i missed that one. I guess i ll have to transform the code so that it will apply to an image instead of this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694522/black-and-white-css-background-on-hover Yet grayscale seem to work? Which filters do work, and which dont?

Comment: It affects the whole div (or in your case the anchor)...If you have content in the div that's affected as well..so, actually, you're not applying the filter to the image but rather the div which has it as a background. If the div has no content then it works the same but that may not be what you are after.

Comment: How does that make it different from this case? In my case I use an anchor, that i'd like to change, that happens to have a background image. So I apply in this case the filter on that anchor, if i am not mistaken. (not that I question your answer, i am just trying to establish where it works on, and what doesn't work. Since my anchor doesn't have anything else in it, it wouldn't affect antyhing else (the text in the anchor is indented far away) or am i seeing this wrong?

Comment: As I said, it's not actually affecting the **image** it's affecting the anchor. Now because there is no actual content in the anchor (at least visually), **in this case** it doesn't matter and the effect is the same. http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KwEKZw